# Query cannot get result when firing multiple threads to get the data

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot application where i am firing 5 DB queries on a postgres table using callable of java concurrent package.

The Table 'User' that i am using is very small and has only 6 entries but still the application is taking more than 40 seconds to display the data and gives an exception after 40 seconds.

**DataServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class DataServiceImpl {
    /*@Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;*/

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Object> showUser(int firstParam, int secondParam) {
        //EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        String sql = "select * from sunny.user where id between ?1 and ?2";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter(1, firstParam);
        query.setParameter(2, secondParam);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private DataServiceImpl dataServiceImpl;

    public List<Object> callUser() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int startParam = 1;
        int endParam = 6;
        List<Future<List<Object>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        List<Object> b = null;
        for (int i = startParam; i < 6; i++) {
            if (i == 1)
                endParam = startParam + 1;
            else {
                startParam += 1;
                endParam += 1;
            }
            Callable<List<Object>> callable = new ProcessingData(startParam, endParam);
            futures.add(executorService.submit(callable));
        }
        executorService.awaitTermination(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        int i = 0;
        for (Future<List<Object>> f : futures) {
            if (i == 0) {
                b = new ArrayList<>(f.get());
            } else {
                b.add(f.get());
            }
            i++;
        }
        return b;
    }

    private class ProcessingData implements Callable<List<Object>> {
        private int firstParam;
        private int secondParam;
        /*
         * @Autowired private DataServiceImpl dataServiceImpl;
         */

        public ProcessingData(int firstParam, int secondParam) {
            super();
            this.firstParam = firstParam;
            this.secondParam = secondParam;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Object> call() throws Exception {
            return dataServiceImpl.showUser(firstParam, secondParam);
       }
    }
}
```

You can find the entire code here - [Git Code Here](https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/TemporaryRepo)

Can anyone please tell me where am i doing wrong?
Exception After 40 seconds:-

```
1  Iftekhar
2  Sunny
2018-05-27 13:29:19.096 ERROR 9836 --- [nio-8085-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at com.example.controller.UserController.showUser(UserController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
```

As you can see that i am only getting data of first 2 rows and exception after that as the other queries are not able to complete within 40 seconds they throw an exception as the value returned by them is null.

**Queries Fired :-**

```
Hibernate: select * from sunny.user where id between ? and ?
Hibernate: select * from sunny.user where id between ? and ?
Hibernate: select * from sunny.user where id between ? and ?
Hibernate: select * from sunny.user where id between ? and ?
Hibernate: select * from sunny.user where id between ? and ?
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @AmitBera :Question Updated please check now.

Comment: Why are you writing code like that? Your exception is also a `ClassCastException`, not related to the other code.

Comment: Are you claiming that `ClassCastException` is lying to you? You have multiple issues here, due to bad code.

Comment: @Kayaman : Yes there is a classCast exception and i want to know the reason for that ... This is a dummy code that is y it is not as per coding standards.. don't wry the actual code has everything.

Comment: Why `nativeQuery` ???

Comment: You want to know the reason for the exception? It's because you're trying to cast an `ArrayList` to `Object[]`. It says right so in the stacktrace.

Comment: You are likely being bitten by use `List<Object>`, which means you have many collections nested in eachother. If you read your code carefully you will realise that you are actually building a `List<List<Object>>`, you are later attempting to cast the members of that result to an `Object[]` as that is was the query returns. Start by removing `Object` throughout and replacing it with a sensible domain POJO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
executorService.awaitTermination(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will block for 40 seconds, but in order for it to even work, you have to call `executorService.shutdown();` first. So try that

```
  executorService.shutdown();
  executorService.awaitTermination(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Moreover, `awaitTermination` returns `boolean` that indicates if timeout was hit(true=task finished normally, false=timeout) or tasks finished before specified period - you seems to neglect that value while I would handle those 2 scenarios differently.

Comment: Even after adding the line - executorService.shutdown(); . I am getting a classCast exception.

Comment: @Sunny if this answer didn't actually answer your question, why did you accept it?

Comment: @BoristheSpider : I have accepted this answer because i need to put  executorService.shutdown(); in my code which was also one of the reason for my exception.